# remove all <a> tags with an class in an html page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can I remove all occurrences of   tags with a particular class only and not the contents inside in it of an html page using jquery or javascript?
For example the following must be converted

```
<a class="ab">
<ol>
<a class="ab">
<li><a class="ab">
abcde</a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="ab">
12354
</a>
</li>
</a>
</ol>
</a>
```

into

```
 <ol>
    <li>
    abcde
    </li>
    <li>
    12354
    </li>
    </ol>
```

I want to remove all a tags with `class= "ab"` with retaining the elements and contents inside it

Comment: id of an element must be unique in a page

Comment: id attributes are supposed to have **unique** values, only one tag on the page can have an `id="ab"`, use a class instead.

Comment: and links can't be nested

Comment: changed id to class in my question

Comment: For reference [W3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H93.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)  , it's brief and works perfectly as you want :[**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jLq96/)**]

```
$("a.ab").replaceWith(function() { return this.innerHTML; });
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<ol>

      <li>

           abcde

      </li>

      <li>

           12354

      </li>

</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try  `replaceWith`

```
jQuery('.ab').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).replaceWith(jQuery(this).html());
});
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/SHReE/

jQuery Api

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 1):

What about unwrap?

```
$('a.ab').contents().unwrap();
```

[contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) - Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.

[unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) - Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

Comment: it keeps this tag inside li elements ,`<li><a class="ab"></a>
abcde
</li>`

Comment: Yes that is because of bad html. Links are not supposed to be nested.

Comment: Yes , That's true ,html is not valid , @Console check my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.ab').each(function() {

    var val = $(this).html();

    $(this).parent().html(val);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
$("a .ab").each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: you also don't need to `each`, this is directly equivalent to `$("a .ab").remove();`

Comment: That would also remove all of the content from inside the links, which isn't the desired result.